# Azure with consul

Tags: azure

I have been trying to use consul with Azure. I have a docker image for my application.

How do I pass the consul url so that my azure container understands to fetch values from consul?

```
docker run -d -e CONSUL_SERVER_URL=http://13.82.147.15:8500 -p 18080:8087
-e BW_PROFILE=CONSUL -e APP_CONFIG_PROFILE=CONSUL -e DBName=getname –e JDBCConnect=connectionurl consulapp:latest
```

I want to pass the following parameter:

```
CONSUL_SERVER_URL=http://13.82.147.15:8500
```

Comment: Just reformatted your question a bit: when you post code, highlight and then hit the curly brackets { }

Answer (score 0):

If *consulapp* is only consuming dns name or service records, then can use consul dns instead; can optionally forward on external queries from that same consul dns server (13.82.147.15):

```
docker run -d --dns=13.82.147.15 --dns-search node.consul --dns-search services.consul -p 18080:8087
-e BW_PROFILE=CONSUL -e APP_CONFIG_PROFILE=CONSUL -e DBName=getname –e JDBCConnect=connectionurl consulapp:latest
```

Assuming that consul dns is configured at 13.82.147.15, port 53. Above example also shows setting dns search domain, using consul default *consul* domain, ie if consulapp pings a "postgres" service, dns will return postgres.service.consul - that is pointing to some IP address.